# Starting Terraform in Azure - Possible to ignore rg=x?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

Is it possible to tell Terraform to ignore rg=x (because stuff in that rg will be managed in the portal so don't freak out if the state changes)?

Many thanks!
Gunnar

Answer (score 1):

On a resource group level, you can only tell terraform to ignore changes which belong to that group's attributes. For example `tags`

```
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [
      # Ignore changes to tags, e.g. because a management agent
      # updates these based on some ruleset managed elsewhere.
      tags,
    ]
  }
```

See https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle.html#ignore_changes for more information.

But if you are not actively managing that resource group, do not import it into Terraform's state at all?

Comment: Thanks a lot! That seems to be it! :)